# How to define schema that will work both in mongoose & graphql

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, schema

How to define a schema that works with React and Graphql promise based.

```
const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your schema like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        __id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I'm gonna try and comment the results

Comment: I'm happy to be able to help.